# instantiation of FragmentTransaction object not possble according to the compiler, Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, instantiation

when I try to instantiate FragmentTransaction() I the the error message:

"can not instantiate the type FragmentTransaction"

in google Android reference it states:

Public Constructors

FragmentTransaction()

so if there is a constructor of FragmentTransaction() then it must be possible to do this,

```
 FragmentTransaction fragtransaction = new FragmentTransaction();
```

the question is WHY is this not possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`FragmentTransaction`, per [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html), is an [abstract](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html) class and therefore cannot be directly instantiated. Instead, you should use `FragmentManager`'s [beginTransaction](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html#beginTransaction%28%29) method to get a valid `FragmentTransaction`